# Find element with specific child element with capybara

Tags: xpath, rspec, capybara

I am trying to write a test in which I need to find an `a` element, that contains a specific icon

`<a href="#"><span class="icon icon-checkmark></span></a>`

I tried using xpath but I am doing something wrong I guess..

```
save_button = find(:xpath, '//a[span(., "icon-checkmark")]')
```

What would be the proper way to find my save button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, except you need to specify that you're looking for a class name.

```
find(:xpath, ".//a[.//span[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' icon-checkmark ')]]")
```

The concat and extra spaces are to make sure it matches the specific class name and not a substring of a different class name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `'*//a/span[contains(@class,'icon-checkmark')]'`

Comment: This will find the <span> not the <a> and will also match an element with a class of 'icon-checkmark2'